# Why my cocoa async socket delegate not working even not return anything?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa, asyncsocket

I was trying connect to a host. I've tried using tls options, or even reading the example of simplehtpp in this git. But in swift 3 why it cants called ?
My log inside any delegate method isn't called . I change my host with anything, same result

```
class FGSocket: NSObject, GCDAsyncSocketDelegate {
    let reachability = Reachability()!
    let Log = Logger()
    var socket: GCDAsyncSocket!
    func connectToHub() {
        Log.info("*** Connecting to Socket ***")
        self.socket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main )

        do {
            try self.socket.connect(toHost: "google.com", onPort: UInt16(80), withTimeout: 60)
            let hubApi : NSString = "google.com"
            let manuallyTrust : NSNumber = true
            Log.info("*** Got to here is connected ?***", self.socket.isConnected)


            //Manually trust
            let options = [
             GCDAsyncSocketManuallyEvaluateTrust : manuallyTrust
             //GCDAsyncSocketSSLPeerID : hubApi
             ] as [String : NSObject]

             Log.info("Requesting StartTLS with options:\n", options);

             self.socket!.startTLS(options)
        } catch {
            Log.error("Error", terminator: "Got error \n")
        }
        Log.info("*** Got to here is connected ?***", self.socket.isConnected)
    }

    func socketDidSecure(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket) {
        Log.info("*** Did Secure to Host ***")
    }

    func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didConnectToHost host: String, port: UInt16) {
        Log.info("*** Did Connect to Host ***")
    }


    func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didConnectTo url: URL){
        Log.info("*** Did Connect to Url ***")
    }

    func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didAcceptNewSocket newSocket: GCDAsyncSocket) {
        Log.info("*** Accept new Socket ***")
    }

}
```

Comment: got same problem, did u solve it?